# Scan []bytes into a json.RawMessage field for a struct

Tags: go

I'm using https://github.com/go-pg/pg, the Postgres golang ORM. It uses `pq` under the hood.

I have a struct with field that uses `json.RawMessage`. Upon loading the data from Postgres, the field's value needs to be scanned.

```golang
type Item struct {
  ID   string  
  Data json.RawMessage `sql:",jsonb"` `json:"data"`

}

func main() {
  item := &Item{}
  db.Model(item).Where("item.ID = $1", "test").Select()

  fmt.Println(Item.Data) // prints nil
}
```

I also tried aliasing `json.RawMessage` like this:

```golang
type JSON json.RawMessage

func (f *JSON) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case []byte:
        *f = v
    case string:
        *f = []byte(v)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot sql.Scan() JSONField from: %#v", value)
    }
    return nil
}

func (f JSON) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if len(f) == 0 {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return string(f), nil
}
```

But I still get `nil`. Seems like I'm supposed to make pointer to `json.RawMessage` but I can't do `type JSON *json.RawMessage`.

I think the problem I'm having is that `json.RawMessage` is a `[]byte` type, and so I need an actual pointer to the slice. Any clean way to do this?

**Ok, I have updated my code using a new `JSON struct` with a `raw *json.RawMessage` field...**

```golang
type Item struct {
  ID   string  
  // the struct for JSON
  Data JSON   `sql:",jsonb"` `json:"data"`

}

type JSON struct {
    // because json.RawMessage is a []byte type, we'll make raw a pointer to it
    raw *json.RawMessage
}

func NewJSON(data string) JSON {
    raw := json.RawMessage(data)
    return JSON{raw: &raw}
}

func (j JSON) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // j.raw is  nil... Scan is not setting the field!!
    if j.raw == nil {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return j.raw.MarshalJSON()
}

func (j JSON) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if j.raw == nil {
        return nil
    }
    err := j.raw.UnmarshalJSON(data)
    return err
}

// Scan occurs when data from postgres is parsed and scanned into the data structure
func (j JSON) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case []byte:
        // create the json.RawMessage
        raw := json.RawMessage(v)
        // assign pointer to raw json.RawMessage field
        j.raw = &raw
        // outside this method, the value j.raw is lost. why? it's a pointer to it.
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot sql.Scan() JSONField from: %#v", value)
    }
    return nil
}

// Value occurs to get the string value of the JSON for the insertion statement
func (j JSON) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if j.raw == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }
    data := *j.raw
    return string(data), nil
}
```

```golang
func main() {
  item := &Item{}
  db.Model(item).Where("item.ID = $1", "test").Select()

  fmt.Println(Item.Data) // prints nil
  bytes, err := json.Marshal(c)
  fmt.Println(err) // no error but the `data` key for the JSON string is nil
}
```

`Scan` is still not working. Check the comments.

Comment: `type JSON json.RawMessage` is not an alias. That's a statement that declares a new type called `JSON` that only has the same _underlying type_ as `json.RawMessage` but is otherwise **COMPLETELY** separate. Have you updated `Item.Data` to `JSON`? Or did you leave it as `json.RawMessage`.

Comment: Also doing `*f = v` in `case []byte:` is "dangerous". The `[]byte` will likely be reused by `database/sql` or `lib/pq` causing unexpected results at best, panic at worst. Use `copy` to create a proper copy of the raw bytes.

Comment: See the last paragraph of the comment to [`Scanner.Scan`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.20.4#Scanner.Scan)

Comment: I got it working using an entirely new `JSON` struct with a pointer field to `*json.RawMessage` but I don't want the `JSON` struct to actually be a struct. I want it to ideally be a `json.RawMessage`

Comment: You can't add methods to imported types. So if you want a field whose type implements the `Scanner` interface, then you _can't_ use `json.RawMessage` because that type does not implement the `Scanner` interface and it's not possible to add methods to it to make it implement the interface.

Comment: I just updated my code. I put the updated code under the bold update text.

Comment: Excellent catch. Fixed that code.

Comment: And both `Scan` AND `UnmarshalJSON` MUST to be declared on pointer receiver.

Comment: So looks like I need the `JSON field` of the `Item struct` to be a pointer to `JSON` then?

Comment: As I've already mentioned in my second comment and provided documentation in my 3rd comment, you MUST do a proper copy of `[]byte` inside Scan. `json.RawMessage(v)` is NOT a proper copy of the data, it just converts the byte slice.

Comment: Both of the options [here](https://go.dev/play/p/FiMCbVWedA3) should work. (Note that the need for proper copy applies to `[]byte` only, when you get a `string` then doing `json.RawMessage(v)` is fine, although it shouldn't matter because the argument to `Scan` for `jsonb` data is much more likely to be `[]byte` instead of `string`)

Comment: Is there a reason why the Data field needs to be of type json.RawMessage?

It might be easier and more straight forward if the field was either a string, or if the fields inside the Data payload were defined in a struct that they could be unmarshalled into.